# How can I make mat-card as mat-grid list view with 2 cards in each row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout, mat-card

I am working with mat-card where I want to put mat-cards as 2x1 ie; 2 cards per row in mobile views and 3 cards per row in tab and laptop view.

I followed [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-mat-grid?file=app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.html) example with grid-list and this is what I want to achieve. I tried with mat-card with the same approach and is not working.

I used flex-layout but it is not proper. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

```
<div class="cardList" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start" fxFlexAlign="stretch" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <mat-card fxFlexAlign="stretch" *ngFor="let member of members" routerLink="/registration/verify-phone">
        <mat-card-header style="flex-direction: column;" fxFlex="60">
            <mat-card-title style="color: #0663fe; font-weight: 600;">{{member.content}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Something like this I need to achieve
[image]